# Oozie email action, how to set a specific "from address"

Tags: email, hadoop, workflow, oozie

I want to set the parameter `oozie.email.from.address` just for one action.

I know oozie-site.xml exists but this sets the parameter for every action.
In one of my workflow.xml I tried this

```
<action name="sendEmail5530">
   <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <configuration>
           <property>
                <name>oozie.email.from.address</name>
                <value>myFromAdress@gmail.com</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>        
        <to>${paramMailList}</to>
        <subject> my subject</subject>
        <body> 
          my body
        </body>
    </email>
    <ok to="mailSent"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

but this does not work.
Have you any better solution? (using only oozie)

Comment: AFAIK the `<property>` element would apply for Hadoop properties only, to be propagated to the child YARN job -- and `<email>` is about the only thing that Oozie does not run in a YARN job anyway...

Comment: The correct place for defining the `oozie.email.from.address` property is `oozie-site.xml`, which will work as global property. Also note that, oozie email action does not have any `configuration` element. Source: [email-action-0.1.xsd](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/client/src/main/resources/email-action-0.1.xsd). The feature you are asking is not available.